# Related rates of an pendulum workings

Tags: calculus

I have an question that I would like to see the workings of.
Pendulum decreasing at rate of 0.100cm/sec. What is the time rate of change of the Period T ( in sec) of the pendulum when L = 16.0 cm , if equation related to period of length is

T = pie * sqrt( L / 245)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$T=2\pi \sqrt{\frac{L}{g}}$$
$$\frac{dT}{dt}= \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{\frac{L}{g}}}.\frac{dL}{dt}$$

You have $\frac{dL}{dt}=-0.001 cm/sec$ , $g=9.8 m/s^2$ and $L=16cm$

Problem. Solved

Comment: Given your question earlier, could you start using `\cdot` instead of `.` when you mean multiplication?